# Calculating the area bounded by three circular arcs on the surface of a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a sphere with equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$ with three arbitrary points on its surface: A = ($x_A, y_A, z_A$), B = ($x_B, y_B, z_B$) and C = ($x_C, y_C, z_C$).

Circular arcs AC, BC and AB are drawn [using the origin as the centre of each circle].

How can I find the area on the surface of the sphere which is enclosed by these three arcs?

Answer (score 3):

Any two of the three vectors ${\bf a}$, ${\bf b}$, ${\bf c}$ span a plane which intersects the sphere in a side of the triangle $\triangle:=\triangle({\bf a},{\bf b},{\bf c})$. In order to compute the area of $\triangle$ we need its angles. These are the angles between said planes, hence we have to compute ${\bf n}_c:={\bf a}\times{\bf b}$, $\ldots\ $. In this way we obtain (check the orientation of the normals!)
$$\cos\alpha= {{\bf n}_b\cdot{\bf n}_c\over|{\bf n}_b|\ |{\bf n}_c|},\quad\ldots\ .$$
The area of $\triangle$ is then given by the formula
$${\rm area}(\triangle)=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi)\>R^2\ .$$